# Avoid VS code autocomplete adding function arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When I input `accel.Tra`, vscode suggest a function call, then if I use `tab` or `enter`, it automatically insert

```
accel.Traverse(const Ray<T> &ray, const I &intersector, H *isect)
```

Then I have to delete those contents in parentheses and write my arguments. How to disable it adding those arguments. Or can I move the cursor between blocks of arguments? For example, I want to move the cursor into the whole `const I &intersector` then I can use backspace to delete the whole block.

From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249878/how-do-i-disable-pop-up-suggestion-for-function-arguments-in-vs-code-with-c-ex), I set `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`. But no use.

Comment: for what langugae? if it's JS/TS, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68265131/11107541

Comment: Maybe, disable `javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls` \
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/how-can-i-make-vs-code-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this here still wondering for me it was an ItelliSense setting that did it

`"editor.suggest.showClasses": false`