# How to get autocomplete for function parameters for JavaScript in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When writing functions like `.addEventListener()` how can I get auto complete and all types of suggestions and information when passing the parameters? For example when I am writing the parameters of this particular function there are many options for the first one which are "click", "drag", "animationend", etc. how can I get a full list of all of these options and also information on all of these options. I have started using VSCode recently and I don't know about most of the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autocomplete feature need to install extension.
E.g for javascript : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Answer (score 1):

To enable autocomplete to work for your own functions, add comments in [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) format just above the function. Example:

```
/**
 * Adds two numbers together.
 *
 * @param {number} a First number to add.
 * @param {number} b Second number to add.
 * @return {number} the sum of a and b.
 */
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [IntelliCode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode) Visual Studio Code extension might help with suggesting the info about function parameters, object properties, and more.

To enable autocomplete function params in VSCode for JavaScript:

1. open Settings (Ctrl + ,)
2. type "JavaScript" in the search bar
3. check "JavaScript › Suggest: Complete Function Calls"

Or if you want to enable this in the settings.json file manually:

1. open Command Pallete (Ctrl + Shift + P)
2. type "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)"
3. paste "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true"