# Disable function signature autofill in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been frustrated by a VSCode feature for some time and am looking for a way to potentially disable it.

When using VSCode to accept an intellicode identified function by using `<tab>` or `<enter>`, VSCode will autofill the remainder of the function name but also fill in the function signature within the parentheses.

For example:

```
fn foo(bar: String) {
  ...
}
```

In VSCode when beginning to type `fo`, it will prompt `foo` as an intellicode autocomplete suggestion.  Hitting `<enter>` will fill in the remainder of the function name but it will also fill the function signature in the parenthesis.  In this example, it will autofill `foo(bar)` where `bar` is highlighted and you're forced to remove the variable and type in the actual param name you'd like.  To make matters worse, while in the autofill signature "mode", autocompletion no longer works as you'd expect.

Is there a way to prevent this?  Ideally, I'd like to hit `<enter>` on `fo` and have it fill in `foo` or even `foo()`.  As it currently stands, upon filling `foo(bar)` I'm required to hit `backspace` and move my cursor out of the function parenthesis, move back into the parenthesis, then continue typing.

This seems to be a non-language-specific issue.  My example is in Rust, for instance, but I've also experienced it in JavaScript/TypeScript.

[example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WIBo.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get autocomplete for function parameters for JavaScript in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265131/how-to-get-autocomplete-for-function-parameters-for-javascript-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching, there appears to be a couple of settings that control this behavior:

`editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` fixes the intellisense autofill behavior.

Then for Rust specifically, `rust-analyzer.completion.callable.snippets` allows you to control whether or not intellisense fills the method signature, adds parenthesis, or neither.  I don't see a setting to change this for other languages, though.

Comment: This doesn't fix it for JavaScript